# flask-user registration form customization

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to add a 'first_name' and 'last_name' to my registration form in Flask, using the flask-user plugin.  I've followed the instructions [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/customization.html) and added the custom Form class, and modified the template.

When I submit the form, however, I just get shown the same page again - and no registration gets stored in the database, nor do I get any error message.  The database table already has the fields for first_name and last_name, and in the web inspector I can see that the data is being sent to the server in the POST request.

Am I missing something?

This is my Python code:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # User authentication information
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')
    reset_password_token = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # User email information
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    # User information
    active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, server_default='')
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, server_default='')

class MyRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    first_name = StringField('First name', validators=[Required('First name is required')])
    last_name  = StringField('Last name',  validators=[Required('Last name is required')])

db.create_all()
# Setup Flask-User
db_adapter = SQLAlchemyAdapter(db, User) # Register the User model
user_manager = UserManager(db_adapter, app, register_form=MyRegisterForm)
```

This is the relevant template HTML from templates/flask_user/register.html:

```
{{ render_field(form.first_name, tabindex=230) }}

{{ render_field(form.last_name, tabindex=230) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `UserProfileForm` class and related views to allow logged in users to enter their `first_name` and `last_name`.  You can use email or username instead for registration.  Or you could do it the other way around: register using email and username then have a `UserProfileForm` where they can enter a username.

But, OK, suppose you want Registration with first and last name, then making sure you are using Flask-User v.1.0.  Use the imports (among others):

```
from flask_user.forms import UserManager, UserMixin, RegisterForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
```

do the usual set-up (not shown here), such as creating your `app = Flask()` object, `db` object from `SQLAlchemy(app)`, and of course your `User` model, as per the [Flask-User (v1.0) docs](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_models.html).

```
class CustomRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    first_name = StringField('First name')
    last_name = StringField('Last name')


class CustomeUserManager(UserManager):
    def customize(self, app):
        self.RegisterFormClass = CustomRegisterForm


user_manager = CustomUserManager(app, db, UserClass=User)
```

I have verified this works, at least to this point (no database set-up mistake, etc.). My screenshot (using the Darkly theme):

[image]

If you also want a `username` field you can do that too, following similar customization steps.